# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'units'

Tags: python, numpy, attributes, attributeerror, metpy

I'm using a new Python package (metpy), which contains several subpackages - one of which defines gradient and wind convergence with the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from ..package_tools import Exporter
from ..constants import g
from ..units import atleast_2d, concatenate, units  
### the 'units' and 'constants' packages are within metpy

exporter = Exporter(globals())

def _gradient(f, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) < f.ndim:
        args = list(args)
        args.extend([units.Quantity(1., 'dimensionless')] * (f.ndim - len(args)))
    grad = np.gradient(f, *args, **kwargs)
    if f.ndim == 1:
        return units.Quantity(grad, f.units / args[0].units)
    return [units.Quantity(g, f.units / dx.units) for dx, g in zip(args, grad)]

def _stack(arrs):
    return concatenate([a[np.newaxis] for a in arrs], axis=0)


def _get_gradients(u, v, dx, dy):
# Helper function for getting convergence and vorticity from 2D arrays
    dudx, dudy = _gradient(u, dx, dy)
    dvdx, dvdy = _gradient(v, dx, dy)
    return dudx, dudy, dvdx, dvdy

def h_convergence(u, v, dx, dy):
    dudx, _, _, dvdy = _get_gradients(u, v, dx, dy)
return dudx + dvdy
```

When I try to use the function h_convergence, I get the following error on this line:

```
if f.ndim == 1:
    return units.Quantity(grad, f.units / args[0].units)
return [units.Quantity(g, f.units / dx.units) for dx, g in zip(args, grad)]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'units'
```

I'm new to Python, but as far as I can tell it's trying to call 'units' from the metpy.units package, not from numpy? Can anyone advise? This isn't my code, but I don't know why it isn't working when I call the h_convergence function.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried the same metpy package and bumped into the same problem:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'units'
```

If you look at the metpy documentation, section 1.2.1 Construction, they explain how to construct these units.

Since I am interested in the convergence as well, I did the following:

```
from metpy.units import units

u1 = u*units('m/s')
v1 = v*units('m/s')
```

and then you should to the same for your dx and dy:

```
dx = dlon * units('m')
dy = dlat * units('m')
```

Final call is then:

```
conv = calc.kinematics.h_convergence(u1,v1,dx,dy)
```

This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get the `units` attribute of `f` (`f.units`), where I'm assuming `f` is of type `numpy.ndarray`. `ndarray`s do not have a `units` attribute, so you get the `AttributeError`.

You need to check what you are feeding to `_gradient` as `f`, which seems to be `u` or `v` from `h_convergence`. Are they meant to be `numpy` arrays, or some other type?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what the issue is. u and v are 2D ndarrays. Can I do anything to make them compatible?

Comment: Sorry I don't know; it isn't my code. I think it's using Pint to be able to convert units? Apologies that is so unhelpful - as I say I'm new and just looking inside pre-written scripts to try and work out what's gone wrong.

Comment: My guess is that `metpy` defines an array subclass, one that adds attributes like `units`.  Your `u` and `v` need to be constructed with that class.

Comment: The documentation says that u and v inputs need to be in the following format: u ((X, Y) ndarray) – x component of the wind
• v ((X, Y) ndarray) – y component of the wind...so I assumed them being ndarrays was fine?

Comment: In the examples it looks like you have to manually add units, e.g. `u = u * units.knot`.